# An explicit embedding of $S^m \times S^n$ into $\mathbb R^{m + n + 1}$.

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

It is a well known that $S^m \times S^n$ can be embedded in $\mathbb R^{m + n + 1}$. Given this fact, it is natural to attempt to describe an embedding explicitly. I think I do have a solution, and was hoping someone here would be able to confirm it.

The embedding is described as follows: Regard $S^m \times S^n$ as $\{ (x_1, \ldots, x_{m+1}, y_1 , \ldots , y_{n+1}) \in  \mathbb R^{m + n + 2} : \Sigma x_i^2 = 1, \Sigma y_j^2 = 1 \}$. We have the inclusion $S^m \times S^n \to 2 S^{m + n + 1}$. Consider the stereographic projection from the north pole $P: 2 S^{m + n + 1} - \{(2,0,\ldots, 0)\} \to \mathbb R^{m + n + 1}$. Of course, this is a standard chart on a sphere of any dimension so its being a diffeomorphism is obvious. Thus $P|_{S^m \times S^n}$ is a diffeomorphism from ${S^m \times S^n}$ onto its image in $\mathbb R^{m + n +1}$ and so gives the desired embedding.

Comment: Hint: try to do the case $m=n=1$ first

Comment: Consider it confirmed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus

Comment: what is the inclusion of $S^m \times S^n \to 2 S^{m+n+1}$?

Comment: @user08 I assume what's meant is that if you take $S^m\times S^n$ as the described subset of $\mathbb R^{m+n+2}$, then every point $(z_1,\ldots,z_{m+n+2})$ of that subset has $\sum z_i^2 = 2$ - i.e. is on a sphere of radius $\sqrt{2}$ embedded in $\mathbb R^{m+n+2}$ - so the construction described does indeed work.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Trust yourself. You can alternatively define $\phi : S^m \times S^n \to S^{n+m+1}, \phi(x,y) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x,y)$. Then the north pole is not in the image of $\phi$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Is there a specific thing you're looking for as an answer with your bounty? I'm a bit perplexed as it is unusual that a question that can be correctly answered by "Yes, that is correct." (possibly with some deeper verification) to receive a bounty.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Apologies, this was simply quite foolish of me: I never noticed that OP answered the question himself! Fortunately I don't care much for math.se karma these days!

Comment: Where do you send the north pole to then?

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli The north pole of the projection is at x_1 = 2, while the embedding from the inclusion only goes up to x_1 = 1, so it doesn't get close to the north pole.

Comment: Is it an isometric embedding though? Or do we need one more dimension for that?

Answer (score 2):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Your solution is absolutely correct. To use the *standard* stereographic projection $s : S^{m + n +1} \setminus \{ N \} \to \mathbb R^{m + n +1}$, where $N = (0,\ldots,0,1)$ is the north pole, I suggest to work with the embedding
$$\phi : S^m \times S^n \to S^{m + n +1}, \phi(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (x,y) .$$
Clearly $N \notin \phi(S^m \times S^n)$.