# $\mathbb{S}^n \times \mathbb{S}^k$ is diffeomorphic to a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

> Prove that $\mathbb{S}^n \times \mathbb{S}^k$ is diffeomorphic to a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}$.

$\mathbb{S}^n \times \mathbb{S}^k \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \times \mathbb{R}^{k+1}=\mathbb{R}^{n+k+2}$.
It's known that $\mathbb{S}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ are diffeomorphic.

but I don't know how to use these facts to solve the exercise, any help please

Comment: You've observed that $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and concluded that $S^n\times S^k \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\times\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. That's true, but instead consider $S^n\times S^k \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\times S^k$ and combine this with your other observation.

Comment: I'd have to $S^n \times S^k \times \mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R}^{n+k+2} \setminus \{0\}$ How can I prove that it is a submanifold? It is easy to see that $S^n$ is a submanifold of $R^{n+1}$ and $S^{k}$ of $R^{k+1}$

Comment: Apply the observation to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\times S^k$ instead.

Comment: $S^n \times S^k \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \times S^k$=$ \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{k+1} \setminus \{0\}$=$\mathbb^{R}^{n+k+1}$, since $S^n \times S^k$ is a manifold of dimension $n + k$ and $S^n \times S^k \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}$, does that show that it is a submanifold?

Comment: Yes, it does. Note, the last equality in your first line should be a subset: $\mathbb{R}^n\times(\mathbb{R}^{k+1}\setminus\{0\}) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}$.

Comment: I still do not understand why the exercise asks to show that there is a diffeomorphism with a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}$. That is, $S^n \times S^k$ is not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}$ ?, I believed that the diffeomorphism that existed was between $S^n \times S^k$ and $S^{n+k}$, and since $S^{n+k}$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}$, then the result would be obtained, but this reasoning is wrong, since $S^n \times S^k$ and $S^{n+k}$ are not difeomorphic Could you give me an explanation, thank you very much

Comment: Here's another approach.  The embedding you wrote is a proper subset of the sphere $S^{n+k+1}$ of radius $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k+2}$.  Now think about stereographic projection.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893592/an-explicit-embedding-of-sm-times-sn-into-mathbb-rm-n-1)

Comment: is there an inclusion of $S^n \times S^k \to 2S^{n+k+1}$?

Comment: What our discussion shows is that there is an embedding $\Phi : S^n\times S^k \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}$. So $\Phi(S^n\times S^k)$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}$ and $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism between $S^n\times S^k$ and $\Phi(S^n\times S^k)$.